# Aplicación en PyQt5 dejó de abrir de repente!

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.9

He diseñado una aplicación en **PyQt5** desde hace algunos meses, hasta el día de ayer me funcionaba todo correctamente, pero el día de hoy lo quise volver a ejecutar y simplemente ya no funciona! Corro el programa y no muestra ninguna ventana, simplemente termina su ejecución. No sé si es algún tema de actualización de librerías. He desinstalado y vuelto a instalar **PyQt5==5.15.4** junto con **pyqt5-tools==5.15.4.3.2**, pero nada.

He probado ejecutar esta sencilla ventana, pero solo llega hasta **"Entro 1"**, nunca ejecuta el `w.show()`, ¿Alguien me puede dar alguna luz? ¿Qué podría ser?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = QWidget()
   w.resize(300,300)
   w.setWindowTitle("Guru99")
   print("Entro1")
   w.show()
   print("Entro2")
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

Si alguien está pasando por lo mismo, mi solución fue crear un entorno virtual (lo instalé desde el cmd -> pip install venv), en donde me descargué todas las librerías necesarias para ejecutar mi aplicación y ahí me funcionó de nuevo!